# GCS Bucket not logging pixel/file requests

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-logging

I have a simple Google Cloud Storage bucket set up that contains one file, pixel.png with a publicly accessible url that is working.

When I go into Stackdriver logging, none of the pixel requests are being tracked... the only thing in the logs are the admin changes I make to the bucket itself:

[image: grid with only folder admin records]

I'm sure it's something simple... The logs for my AppEngine app records every single image request by my app, I'd like to set the bucket up the same way - to see each request for pixel.png.

Comment: Have you looked at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#delivery? It looks like it matches your use case (from the docs : *You most likely want to use access logs if: You want to track access to public objects.*) So you'd probably want to enable logging on your bucket with something like `gsutil logging set on -b gs://your-bucket [...]`.

Comment: I did go through that, and each step was successful - but the new logging bucket is the same way: It doesn't log the .png requests. Not understanding why a second bucket is necessary for logging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with Cloud Audit logging for Google Cloud Storage, it is important to read this page in detail: [Cloud Audit Logging with Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logs).   For your particular puzzle, it is important to realize that Audit Logging is switched *off* by default.  To switch it on you should visit `IAM & admin > Audit Logging` in the GCP console and switch it on for Cloud Storage.  The second thing that I noted in your question was that the object in question may be public?  There is a caveat in the audit logging for cloud storage which reads:

> Cloud Audit Logging does not track access to public objects.

So if the object in question is public, access is not reported by Cloud Audit logging.

Comment: That's good reference. I've gone through their serverless pixel tracking tutorial - which implies that it is possible, but that's a bigger issue - I'll create a new question for that. Tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/serverless-pixel-tracking-tutorial

Comment: [Also](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#should-you-use) "You most likely want to use access logs if: ...  You want to track access to public objects."